# Display board using raspberry pi

Tags: python, display

I have to make a display board using raspberry pi. The display board will be showing some sort of counter and 1920x1080 32 inch LCD screen will be used for display. Thus I have decided to use pygame to code my application. The counter will be update at every 2 seconds and interrupt on gpio pins will update counter. Thus my question is pygame good choice to make such application? How much will cpu usage when application is running considering the fact that I have to display it on 32 inch Full HD LCD and it will running for 23 hours per day? Any guesses or suggestion since I don't have access to raspberry pi yet. Also I can't use html to display the counter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't really need a significant amount of CPU while you're not updating the screen. Just don't flip or update the display until you get an interrupt